# GravityForm email address layout

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

Case: When a user submits a (Gravity)form and the email is received. Under the address section there is a Map It link, which links to the google maps to the specified address.

Question: How to show this link just for specific forms. It should be something like

```
 if( $form['id'] == '101' ) {
}
```

But im struggling implementing this. The Map It code is defined in /wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/includes/fieldsclass-gf-field-address.php file. Line 905 //adding map link .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Direct add your link in "notification" area ...